# HttpContext.Current is null while trying to register types into IoC container

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, unity-container

I am trying to setup IoC container in my ASP.NET MVC 5 application so I can access these objects anywhere in my application.

I choose to use [Unity.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc/) container for the job.

During my type registration step, I am trying to run the following code

```
var httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
container.RegisterInstance<HttpContextBase>(httpContext);

var sessionWrapper = new HttpSessionStateWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Session);
container.RegisterInstance<HttpSessionStateBase>(sessionWrapper);

var httpServerUtility = new HttpServerUtilityWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Server);
container.RegisterInstance<HttpServerUtilityBase>(httpServerUtility);
```

However, the line `HttpContext.Current.Session` is throwing a null exception as the `HttpContext.Current` object is **null**.

How can I correctly inject a non-null `HttpContextWrapper` instance into my IoC container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I correctly inject a non-null HttpContextWrapper instance into my IoC container?

These lines cover all 3 cases (`HttpContext`, `HttpContext.Session`, and `HttpContext.Server`):

```
var httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
container.RegisterInstance<HttpContextBase>(httpContext);
```

Since there are no sessions during application startup, you cannot access them this early in the [MVC 5 Application Lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application).

Once you have injected `httpContext` into a component, you can access the session state in the *runtime* part of the application.

```
public class SomeService : ISomeService
{
    private readonly HttpContextBase httpContext;

    public SomeService(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContext));
        this.httpContext = httpContext;
        // Session state is still null here...
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // At runtime session state is available.
        var session = httpContext.Session;
    }
}
```

> **NOTE:** It is generally not a good practice to make your services depend directly on session state. Instead, you should have the controller pass session state values through method parameters (i.e. `DoSomething(sessionValue)`), or alternatively implement a `SessionStateAccessor` wrapper around `HttpContextBase` that can be injected into your services, similar to how it is done in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Does that also mean it should be safe of add a condition in the registration section to only register them if `HttpContext.Current != null`? So they wont get registered at app start up, but will get registered on the next request, right?

Comment: Nope. Application startup happens *once* per application start. It is not possible to access any of the *runtime state* of the application there. Instead, you *compose* the application at application startup and do any runtime activity (such as sessions) within the services that are composed.

Comment: I have the following 2 attributes on my `UnityMvcActivator` class `[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(Core.UnityMvcActivator), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethod(typeof(Core.UnityMvcActivator), "Shutdown")]` are you saying to run the `Start` method `PostApplicationStartMethod` instead of `PreApplicationStartMethod`?

Comment: No, it sounds like you are composing the application correctly at startup in the [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

Comment: What I am saying is that you should hold off until runtime to try to access stuff that is not available until runtime. You don't need to *compose* it or *inject* it because it is part of the runtime state of the application that happens long after everything is composed. Think of it like pitching a tent. You do it once per sundown and the tent stands on its own. The snoring happens *inside* of the tent and can occur all night. Snoring while pitching a tent is not going to happen. You have to wait until you are inside of the tent.

Comment: I guess the better question would then be, How can I correctly add my HttpContext info into my IoC container then? I am using IoC for the first time, so I am trying to learn the right way. At this point all I like to do is have the HttpContext stuff in the container so when I need to use them in my classes at run time, I can find them

Comment: I have edited my answer to try to make it more clear. Those 2 lines can replace all 6 of the lines you are using. You don't need to register runtime state at application startup. Instead, it flows through the application at runtime *through the `HttpContextBase` instance that is injected at startup*. Simply refrain from using those properties of `HttpContextBase` until you are inside of a context they can be used in.

Comment: the line `var httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)` throw ArgumentNullException if I use the `PreApplicationStartMethod`